# Three columns index

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have the following table:

> questions (id, title, user_id, ask_id (nullable), created_at)

i have the following three queries:

> 1. select * from questions where user_id = ? order by created_at desc;
> 2. select * from questions where user_id = ? and ask_id is not null order by created_at desc;
> 3. select * from questions where ask_id = ? order by created_at desc;

Whats the best way to optimize those queries?
Is it possible to use a single index that would help avoid using file sort?

Answer (score 1):

No. Create two different indexes for user_id and ask_id

Comment: what about `created_at` column? how can we avoid file sort for all those queries? maybe we need 3 indexes?

Comment: MySQL won't (usually) use two indexes.  But it may use a 'composite' index.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(user_id, created_at) -- for #1
INDEX(ask_id, created_at) -- for #3
```

The first one will help *somewhat* for #2.

"Filesort" is not as evil as everyone makes out.  It is merely a clue that you either don't have the best index, or that the query is complex enough to *require* one or more sorts.

If this is a large table and you don't really use `id`, there are other optimizations I could suggest.